# How to use a method from one Activity in another Activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to use my method `onImageFromCameraClick` in another Activity, but when I try to use it from my other Activity, it causes the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

How can I use that method in another Activity?

Method `onImageFromCameraClick()`:

```
public void onImageFromCameraClick() {  
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  

 if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {  
    File photoFile = null;  
 try {  photoFile = createImageFile();  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
  }  

    if (photoFile != null) {  
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,     
        getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);  
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);  
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
  } // inner if end  
  } // outer if end  
} // onImageFromCameraClick END
```

**OtherActivity**:

```
case "cameraStart":  

  Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());  
  mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
  @Override  
  public void run() {  
  FaceDetectionActivity fm = new FaceDetectionActivity();  
  fm.onImageFromCameraClick();  
  }  }, 0);  
 break;  }  
 break;  
  // Code end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try using the `Context` of your main class that contains the `onImageFromCameraClick()` to initialize a reference to the main class in the other `Activity`, for example:

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) context;
main.onImageFromCameraClick();
```

You can obtain the `context` from your main class by passing an instance of `this` into your other activity.

Comment: @Namkun No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I this this is because your FaceDetectionActivity is create by **new** .
I got this for you:

```
public void onImageFromCameraClick() {
...
    getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
...
}
```

Comment: I think `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Below is not possible.

```
FaceDetectionActivity fm = new FaceDetectionActivity();  
fm.onImageFromCameraClick();
```

Before giving solution, I would suggest you to read Android first.

Now solution is to move `onImageFromCameraClick()` to utility class, and pass Context to it as `onImageFromCameraClick(Context context){}`. Use this context instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: I think `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` is not working.